# How do you send email from a java application while using an obscure domain?

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send an email from an email account that uses a hostmonster domain.  I have been using code that I found in another post that works great for gmail but I am having trouble adapting it to suit this domain.  The original code is:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
    String host = "smpt.gmail.com";
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

From this I have changed the host and the port to fit my domain.  The host being "host407.hostmonster.com" and the outgoing smtp port being 465.  When I run my application with these changes nothing happens.  I don't get an error that my code couldn't connect to a server, the password was wrong, or any other feedback, it just keeps running while when I used it with gmail it took between two and three seconds to run the application and send several emails.  I am completely at a loss for what to try and I haven't been able to find any posts here about using an email other than big name domains, so any help will be appreciated!

Edit:  I should have included all of my own code sorry, here it is:

```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.util.*;
   import javax.mail.*;
   import javax.mail.internet.*;
   public class Formater {

private static String USER_NAME = "***********";  // GMail user name (just the part before "@gmail.com")
private static String PASSWORD = "********"; // GMail password
private static String[] RECIPIENTS = { "***************", "*************"}; //"******************",
private static String WeatherText = "This is where the weather text will be and how it will look.";
private static File outputFolder = new File("C:/Users/***** *******/Documents/**********/Output/Test.txt");
private static ArrayList<String> Text = new ArrayList<>();


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String from = USER_NAME;
    String pass = PASSWORD;
    String[] to = { "**************"}; // list of recipient email addresses
    String[] bcc =  RECIPIENTS;
    String subject = "Java send mail example";
    String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";
    sendFromMail(from, pass, to, bcc, subject, body);

}

private static void sendFromMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String[] bcc, String subject, String body) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    String host = "host407.hostmonster.com";
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
        InternetAddress[] bccAddress = new InternetAddress[bcc.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i <bcc.length;i++){
            bccAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(bcc[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i<bccAddress.length; i++){
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddress[i]);
        }
        message.setSubject(subject);
        //message.setText(body); 
        message.setContent("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
```

Comment: Nothing happens because application execution ends, or you think that nothing is happening and the connection is waiting for throwing timeout?

Comment: Please, specify the library you are using and also try to enable any debug it might have. It shouldn't be nothing related yo your specific domain. Also try and paste the actual code you are using, not the example from gmail.

Comment: Nothing happens because the application continues to run when it should stop once the emails are sent, and my SDK shows that it is still running in the bottom right corner.

Comment: If the code works for some smtp (Gmail) it most likely is correct, you probably should ask the other smtp admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got bored and just started trying random ports to see if maybe one would work, and the third port (587) I tried worked.